# How to work with an object in a backbone model?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, handlebars.js, marionette

I have a model, it's data structure looks like this.

```
var myModel = {
    _id: 798698,
    username: "John",
    message: {
        message1: "Some cool messsage",
        message2: "I'm mad Ohio State lost"
    }
}
```

In working with backbone collections and handlebars, if I were to loop all the messages from each model. ex

```
var model1 = {
    _id: 97878,
    username: "Tony",
    message: {
        message1: "March Madness baby!",
        message2: "Hey There Jason!"
    }
}

var model2 = {
    _id: 86899,
    username: "Jason",
    message: {
        message1: "Hey Tony!",
        message2: "You watching the game?",
    }
}
```

Then in a `.hbs`

```
{{#each message}}
    <div class="message">
        {{../username}}: {{this}}
    </div>
{{/each}}
```

The problem is in a collection view, when I loop the models each set of messages gets its own `el` example.

```
var Marionette = require('backbone.marionette');

var ChatView = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    className: 'model',
    template: require('../../templates/message.hbs')
});

module.exports = CollectionView = Marionette.CollectionView.extend({
    className: 'collection',
    initialize: function() {
        this.listenTo(this.collection, 'change', this.render);
    },
    itemView: ChatView
});
```

Code like the above would result in something like this.

```
<div class="collection">
    <div class="model">
        <div class="message">
            Tony: March Madness baby!
        </div>
        <div class="message">
            Tony: Hey There Jason!
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="model">
        <div class="message">
            Jason: Hey Tony!
        </div>
        <div class="message">
            Jason: You watching the game?
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

But the problem is, I want a straight list of messages, so that when I add a `date sent` property I can sort the order of the messages from old to new. Also if the interaction goes, "Tony", "Jason", "Tony", "Jason" and is out of order then there is a problem. But when a `date` and `time` is added I can sort the list.

So I think my question is quite clear, basically I need help getting the markup to be a straight list, and not wrapped by the model, which in the database it is, so the html nicely represents the data model, but that's counter productive to what I am trying to accomplish.

Comment: Can you post a snippit of what you want the HTML to look like? It's not quite clear. The way it's being rendered is exactly how the CollectionView/ItemView works

Comment: Out-of-the-box Backbone doesn't work well with nested data. In the pure Backbone way of doing things, each of your models `message` objects looks like another collection.

Comment: just take the `<div class="model">` out so there is a list of `<div class="message">`

Comment: Yeah I know it doesnt I knew this would complicate things using a strucutre like that but I am hoping some one has a better idea.

Comment: Yeah, the data format is really hurting it. You need a parent $el to delegate events to. If each of the chat messages doesn't have any events bound, you could render the HTML all in 1 big view...

Comment: Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/CoryDanielson/CQ4K8/ But I really think you should go back and work the format of your data... it could end of being something that continues to cause problems. Like, I'm not sure how you would sort messages by time if each message doesn't have it's own timestamp.

Comment: Also, how can a user click on a message and delete it if each doesn't have it's own _id

Comment: Good points, thanks for the link.. I am super tired been working on this app all day.. Ill get back into first thing in the morning!!

Comment: The midnight grind comes to an end :D btw, I picked Stephen A. Austin over VCU in all my brackets :D didn't pick Hardvard, Dayton, Mercer or Stanford though ................. classic march madness

Comment: I think Dayton was the first bracket buster for everyone. Hate to get off topic, but cool you're also watching the madness!!! Ill talk to you tomorrow and check out that fiddle...

Comment: Good fiddle, got a chance to look at it. You're right if I wanted to add a date/time property I would have to further nest the object. I may open a new question and ask about setting up the data structure. Thanks for taking the time to make that, backbone fiddles can take time, since you got to include all the dependencies, so I appreciate that.

Comment: Let me know what you think, should I just go ahead and figure out a better structure?

Comment: Yeah, I would have each message with it's own _id, author_id, recipient_id, timestamp, and message. Then on the front-end you could lookup the author_id to get their username & picture or something if needed. Or if you want group chat, instead of a recipient_id referencing another user, use a chat_room_id that multiple users can have access too.

Comment: Yeah I opened another question and it seems like the best way to go. There are things like backbone relational and I am using marionette I think there is something in marionette that helps with this. Seems counter intuitive to me but whatever works the best. Thanks for the help.